# JsonProperty is being ignored when Serialized for Office Addin

Tags: c#, json, json.net, visual-studio-addins

When Serialized the jsonproperty is ignored. The same piece of code is working for a console application. But when I use the same piece of code for developing a Microsoft office add-in then I get this problem.

Expected Result :{"jql":"test ORDER BY UPDATED DESC","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"fields":[]}

Actual Result: {"JQL":"test ORDER BY UPDATED DESC","StartAt":0,"MaxResults":50,"Fields":[]}

```
public class SearchRequest
{

    [JsonProperty("jql")]
    public string JQL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("startAt")]
    public int StartAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("maxResults")]
    public int MaxResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public List<string> Fields { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SearchRequest")]
    public SearchRequest()
    {
        Fields = new List<string>();
    }
}

public void ViewCases_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
             request.JQL = "test ORDER BY UPDATED DESC";
            request.MaxResults = 50;
            request.StartAt = 0;
   string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
}
```

Comment: That's not ignoring its because of the Json serializer you are using and its settings, in console you use a different serilaizer therefore it behaves as expected